# How to use JQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Please, I need a little bit help. ( I'm not a user experience developer) 
I have a school Web "carpooling" application project. 
I try to use jquery autocomplete to display places of departure and arrival.

I have this function uses a web service (that returns the names and id of places according to the user's input)

```js
auto=function(){
 var query=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var u = "http://covoiturage.hhacherouf.info/trips/autocomplete-place"+"?query="+query;
 $.ajax({
    url: u,
    contentType: "application/json",
    method: "GET",
 })
 .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 localStorage.setItem("placeId",data.placeId);
 localStorage.setItem("description",data.description);
 });
}
```

for exemple  If the user enters a character string Paris, response will be : 
[ {
  "placeId" : "ChIJD7fiBh9u5kcRYJSMaMOCCwQ",
  "description" : "Paris, France"
}, {
  "placeId" : "ChIJPbgDXcoqrBIRf74-UUHi4z4",
  "description" : "Parisot, France"
}, {
  "placeId" : "ChIJPb3wuJFZ8kcREOAOszTOCQQ",
  "description" : "Paris-l'Hôpital, France"
}, {
  "placeId" : "ChIJ40p0EoXQ3UcRENJjgT7xCgQ",
  "description" : "Le Touquet-Paris-Plage, France"
}, {
  "placeId" : "ChIJ18V5kFPd80cRU075_QZazHE",
  "description" : "Paray-le-Monial, France"
} ]

I want my textfield display names from  auto function request.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is happening right now?

Comment: i started to code the function { textfield display names from auto function request} but i don't know how to recover the value of description  for use in autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var u = "auto()";
   $('#departure').autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response){
     $.ajax({
      url:u,
      datatype:json,
      data:{q:request.term},
      sucess:function(data){
       response(data);
      }
     });
    },
    minLength:1,
    select:function(event,ui){
     alert("selection:"+ ui.item.label);
    }
   });
    });
});
```